# Tomcat Clustering and HTTPS Issue

Tags: tomcat, cluster-computing, mod-proxy

I have two instances of Tomcat 6 with content accessible via HTTP and HTTPS for other pages.

I have configured the instances this way:

1. Instance one to listen on port 8080(HTTP) and 8443(HTTPS)
2. Instance two to listen on port 7080(HTTP) and 7443(HTTPS)

I have mod_proxy configured with Apache 2.2 to do clustering.

The requests are coming in properly and all works well for HTTP traffic but when you are in the app and it becomes HTTPS then I get the page cannot be found when tomcat tries to serve the page.

Now if I access the two tomcat instances directly bypassing the load balancer then everything is fine. So http/https is configured properly on tomcat but not on Apache.

I have a feeling I must configure Apache to handle this(or mod_proxy).

Answer (score 0):

It's better to just use the [ajp13 connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/config/ajp.html) to attach Apache to Tomcat and let Apache take care of the https vs. http.  Then Tomcat just needs to listen on, say 8009 and 7009 for the two instances and you are all set.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I might have to do that but was trying to keep the configuration of the existing tomcat servers the same, Well one of them.  Hopefully I can convince the owner of the Tomcat instances to move the https configuration from Tomcat to Apache.  It makes sense to configure it once on apache and go from there. If the answer is know that they want to keep the Tomcats configuration as is is there a way to do it the way I mentinoned.  Thanks.

Comment: Is your apache server setup to allow HTTPS?  If you aren't serving port 443 for your virtual hosts, then serving HTTPS definitely not going to work in redirects.

Comment: The Apache Server isn't setup for HTTPS yet. Only the 2 Tomcats instances.